# Hibernate : Load all subclasses by single query (single-table inheritance)

Tags: spring, performance, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

We decided to use hibernate inheritance mapping strategy with discriminator ( see 10.1.3 : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass-discriminator ) for loading of relatively small amount of **read-only** data ( ~ 20 000 rows in single table, 80 entity types, each row contains in average 100 characters).

When application starts hibernate loads these entities via ~80 queries + another ~150 queries is made to establish relationships between them. This is of course time consuming and unnecessary.

I would not mind to load whole table by single query, but how to get entity type mapping right as we use discriminator column ?

Of course there is always option to load & map it manually but we would like to stick with hibernate.

*hibernate configuration of abstract entity :*

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 30)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "MAIN_TABLE")
public abstract class ApplicationAbstractEntity 
...
```

*subclass configuration example :*

```
@Entity
public class SomeSubEntity extends ApplicationAbstractEntity  
...
```

*Load entities for given subclass (this repeats for each subclass, 80 entity types = 80 queries) :*

```
currentHibernateSession.createCriteria(SomeSubEntity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setResultTransformer` with your custom transformer to map result to your entities.

You can load all your entities with one query like

```
currentHibernateSession.createCriteria(ApplicationAbstractEntity.class).setResultTransformer(new CustomResultTransformer());
```